# How can I replace a substring with some other substring in the values of objects of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, javascript-objects, replaceall

```
var temp = [
  {
    text:'some text and then % sign and then, again % sign',
    link: 'another text with %',
  },
 ];
```

I want to replace all `%` signs with `\%` in the `temp` array of objects. How can I do it?

**Desired Output:**

```
var temp = [
  {
    text:'some text and then \% sign and then, again \% sign',
    link: 'another text with \%',
  },
 ];
```

I've tried these two ways, but, none of them worked:

**First one is using a for loop:**

```
for(let i = 0; i<temp.length; i++) {
    temp[i].text = temp[i].text.replace(/%/g, '\\%');
    temp[i].link = temp[i].link.replace(/%/g, '\\%');
}
```

**Output:** It resulted in two backslashes.

```
[
    {
        text: 'some text and then \\% sign and then, again \\% sign',
        link: 'another text with \\%'
    }
]
```

**Second way is using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify:**

```
temp = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(temp).replace(/%/g, '\\%')
);
```

**Output:** Compilation Error

```
undefined:1
[{"text":"some text and then % sign and then, again % sign","link":"another text with %"}]^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 30at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/bRVTxjVcfu.js:62:15)at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Comment: A \ needs to be escaped in a string, so the result of \\% is correct and evaluates to \%

Comment: Yes, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could just slit and rejoin:

```
const parsedTemp = temp.map(tempItem => Object.entries(tempItem)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>
    ({...acc, [key]: value.split('%').join('\\%')}), {})
)
```

Disclaimer - haven't tested for errors but logic is sound

EDIT:
I forgot you need to escape the backslash - It will appear as '\\%' in your string, but that is correct.

Comment: When I'm console logging parsedTemp, It is showing `[ undefined ]`. Also, you are missing one open curly bracket in `.reduce`

Comment: Thanks @GovindTomar - yes you are right - there we an extra bracket which I have removed. I also forgot to escape the backslash. I have edited now and tested.

Comment: When I'm console logging `parsedTemp`, it is showing the result with two backslashes. And when I'm console logging `parsedTemp[0].text`, it is showing the desired output which is with one backslash. What is this behavior and why is this happening?

Comment: '\\%' in a js string means '\%' when rendered. The backslash is a special character called an escape. It allows you to use other special character combinations such as linebreak: '\n'.
So the only way to have a backslash in your string is to escape that too: '\\' in a js string is the same as '\' when you come to render it.

Comment: Then, why is it showing two backslashes, when I'm console logging `parsedTemp`?

Comment: So you can see what is actually in the string - the same reason '/n' would show when logging a string, but would appear as a line break (without '\n') when rendered.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const temp = [{
  text: 'some text and then % sign and then, again % sign',
  link: 'another text with %',
}, ];

for (const obj of temp) {
  for (const key in obj) {
    obj[key] = obj[key].replace(/%/g, String.raw`\%`)
  }
}

console.log(temp)
```

Comment: It results in two backslashes. Try running the code

Comment: I know, creating a string with a single backslash is impossible

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by iterating the `temp` array with the help of [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and then by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you can replace the sub string of the whole string by using [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var temp = [
  {
    text:'some text and then % sign and then, again % sign',
    link: 'another text with %'
  }
];

temp.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = obj[key].replaceAll('%', '\\%')
  })
});

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: You have used forwardslash while the result requires a backslash.

Comment: It results in two backslashes. There should only be one backslash.

Comment: @GovindTomar In stackoverflow code snippet it is looks like two backslashes but if you will run this in jsfiddle it will show only one. There is some limitation on SO. Here is the working fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/92sg5cf4/